# Cursor in function error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'xxx' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, user-defined-functions

when I try to use my udf i get an error saying:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Mar A' to data type int.

I use northwind database and here's my code:

```
alter function test_fu (@city varchar(70))
returns varchar(70)
as
begin
declare @name varchar(70)
declare kursor cursor
for (select [ContactName]
from Contacts
where City = @city)
open kursor
fetch next from kursor into @name
set @name=@name+1
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
close kursor
Deallocate kursor
return @name
end
```

Comment: `set @name=@name+1`???

Comment: when i delete this line i get an error saying  "Cursor is not open." so i thought it is required

Comment: You should describe exactly what it is you want to do, a cursor is likely not the correct solution to your problem and its hard to see what your current code is attempting to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get every ContactName from Contacts table which is being assigned to a specified city, by using user defined function

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your cursor has logical errors, move the `while @@FETCH_STATUS=0` right after the cursor opening, then execute something and move it to next value

```
begin
print 'your current selected name is: '+@name
fetch next from kursor into @name
end
```

Check the edits:

use AdventureWorks2017

```
declare @name varchar(70)
declare kursor cursor
for (
    select firstname
    from Person.Person
    where Person.Title = 'Mr.'
)

open kursor
fetch next from kursor into @name
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0

begin
print 'your current selected name is: '+@name
-- your statement goes here
fetch next from kursor into @name
end

close kursor
Deallocate kursor
```

But anyway i agree with Gordon's answer: there are several other ways (better ways actually) to avoid using cursor in described situation

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a cursor for this?

```
alter function test_fu (@city varchar(70))
returns varchar(70)
as
begin
    declare @name varchar(70)

    select top (1) @name = ContactName
    from Contacts
    where City = @city;

    return @name;
end;
```

This structure brings up a fundamental question about the data structure:  Does each city really have only one contact?  If not, which one do you want?  I suspect that this function is not really doing anything particularly useful, even if it were working.

Comment: I thought about that at first, but I would like to get multiple variables by that function. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Rocket128 . . . That has nothing to do with a cursor.  You should look into inline table-valued functions:  http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-inline-table-valued-functions-better-than-a-view/.